Can not load with SimpleDirectoryReader (llama.core), offline VM
I try to load some documents (docx, doc, ppt, pdf, txt) with llama on a offline VM:
from llama_index.core import SimpleDirectoryReader
reader = SimpleDirectoryReader(input_dir="C:/Docs/").load_data(num_workers=10)`

And i havre this error :
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\samuel.flahaut\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\samuel.flahaut\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 72, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\socket.py", line 963, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\samuel.flahaut\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 715, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\samuel.flahaut\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 404, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\samuel.flahaut\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1058, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\samuel.flahaut\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 363, in connect
    self.sock = conn = self._new_conn()
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\samuel.flahaut\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 186, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000024AC24A15E0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\samuel.flahaut\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 799, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\samuel.flahaut\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='huggingface.co', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /nlpconnect/vit-gpt2-image-captioning/resolve/main/config.json (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000024AC24A15E0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\file_download.py", line 1261, in hf_hub_download
    metadata = get_hf_file_metadata(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\utils\_validators.py", line 119, in _inner_fn
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\file_download.py", line 1674, in get_hf_file_metadata
    r = _request_wrapper(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\file_download.py", line 369, in _request_wrapper
    response = _request_wrapper(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\file_download.py", line 392, in _request_wrapper
    response = get_session().request(method=method, url=url, **params)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\utils\_http.py", line 68, in send
    return super().send(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 519, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: (MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='huggingface.co', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /nlpconnect/vit-gpt2-image-captioning/resolve/main/config.json (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000024AC24A15E0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed'))"), '(Request ID: 076e991f-82f3-41a9-b1a3-c94698da25dc)')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\transformers\utils\hub.py", line 398, in cached_file
    resolved_file = hf_hub_download(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\utils\_validators.py", line 119, in _inner_fn
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\file_download.py", line 1406, in hf_hub_download
    raise LocalEntryNotFoundError(
huggingface_hub.utils._errors.LocalEntryNotFoundError: An error happened while trying to locate the file on the Hub and we cannot find the requested files in the local cache. Please check your connection and try again or make sure your Internet connection is on.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 51, in starmapstar
    return list(itertools.starmap(args[0], args[1]))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\llama_index\core\readers\file\base.py", line 408, in load_file
    file_extractor[file_suffix] = reader_cls()
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\llama_index\readers\file\slides\base.py", line 42, in __init__
    model = VisionEncoderDecoderModel.from_pretrained(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\transformers\models\vision_encoder_decoder\modeling_vision_encoder_decoder.py", line 359, in from_pretrained
    return super().from_pretrained(pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\transformers\modeling_utils.py", line 3006, in from_pretrained
    config, model_kwargs = cls.config_class.from_pretrained(
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\transformers\configuration_utils.py", line 602, in from_pretrained
    config_dict, kwargs = cls.get_config_dict(pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\transformers\configuration_utils.py", line 631, in get_config_dict
    config_dict, kwargs = cls._get_config_dict(pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\transformers\configuration_utils.py", line 686, in _get_config_dict
    resolved_config_file = cached_file(
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\transformers\utils\hub.py", line 441, in cached_file
    raise EnvironmentError(
OSError: We couldn't connect to 'https://huggingface.co' to load this file, couldn't find it in the cached files and it looks like nlpconnect/vit-gpt2-image-captioning is not the path to a directory containing a file named config.json.
Checkout your internet connection or see how to run the library in offline mode at 'https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/installation#offline-mode'.
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    reader = SimpleDirectoryReader(input_dir="C:/Docs pour LM/CLA2k").load_data(num_workers=10)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\llama_index\core\readers\file\base.py", line 543, in load_data
    results = p.starmap(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 375, in starmap
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, starmapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 774, in get
    raise self._value
OSError: We couldn't connect to 'https://huggingface.co' to load this file, couldn't find it in the cached files and it looks like nlpconnect/vit-gpt2-image-captioning is not the path to a directory containing a file named config.json.
Checkout your internet connection or see how to run the library in offline mode at 'https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/installation#offline-mode'.

If anyone understands... thank you in advance.
My hope : No error and that documents are loaded.
And now i write some words because i can post this message without this...
_What does Edge say when it comes to Chrome?
"Hey! Browser!"
_Why Astronauts use Linux?
Because Astronauts can not open windows.
